# C++ template function, substitution failure skip the implementation

Tags: c++, template-specialization

I have following code just for testing, the template function is used twice, the first time it is ok. In second case, I create a pointer and pass the pointer as a reference into the template function. I expected the line "obj.~T()" failed compile time. But actually the code compiles and runs fine. When I debug through the function, the program simply skip the obj.~T(); I am using VC10.

My question is:
1. Is this a expected behavior? If it is based on which section from the c++ standrade?
2. Any pro and con about this behavior??? In my case it is good since no compile error neither run time error. But there might be some situation I do not know but do damage the code.

Thanks

```
template<typename T>
void ptrDest(T& obj)
{
  obj.~T();
}

class Dummy
{
public:
  Dummy(){}
  ~Dummy(){ cout << "dest" <<endl;}
};

int main()
{
  Dummy d;
  ptrDest(d);

  Dummy* pd = new Dummy();
  ptrDest(pd);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The behaviour is undefined when `main()` exits because `d` will be destroyed twice. But before that point, it should output `dest` twice and that is what I see when I run it your code. What output are you getting?

Comment: Is it OK even if `obj.~T()` being skipped means the 2nd Dummy's destructor not be called.

Comment: @songyuanyao I wouldn't be so concerned with UB; this looks like a compiler bug. If you want to make the behavior defined, then add `new( & d ) Dummy;` after `ptrDest(d);`.

Comment: What are you trying to test in your code?

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Do not think the variable d's destructor is called twice is a problem. The destructor is just a function get invoked right before a instance is destroyed but the function itself does not destroy the instance~~~ Except we do something weird in destructor e.g delete this... :D or delete something already deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Template substitution results in either a *pseudo-destructor call* expression or a function invocation of the destructor. These are identical things in the language grammar, but semantically different:

- A pseudo-destructor call (C++11 §5.2.4) is allowed for a primitive type such as a pointer, and it does nothing.
- An explicit destructor invocation is a function call which goes through name lookup and forms a function call expression (C++11 §5.2.2).

Anything matching the syntax of a pseudo-destructor call in a template is also potentially a well-formed function call (explicit destructor invocation), and vice versa.

So, if you see two messages for the destructor of `d` and none for `dp`, you are observing the expected behavior.

Comment: Based on this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455216/are-pointers-primitive-types-in-c" pointer is a compound type. I guess because there are function pointer and class member/function pointers

Comment: @rongyang Compound types may still primitive (non-class) types. The Standardese term is *scalar type* but I find that to sound a little confusing, as pointers cannot be "scaled."

Answer (score 6):

This is an **explicit destructor call**, and it is a valid operation, although not necessarily considered a good practice. Think of using scoped variables instead, if possible.

In your second call, you are actually trying to call the *destructor of the pointer*, which indeed does not exists, instead of the destructor of the pointed object, and this is why it skips it. Be advised, though, that your Dummy object is still allocated after the second call, and you will leak in all circumstances.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. So in the second call, the pointer's destructor is a pseudo destructor (based on Potatoswatter's reply) is that the reason that line of code is not executed?

Comment: @rongyang There is no such thing as "the destructor of the pointer." *Pseudo-destructor-name* is just a syntactic element which looks like the name of a destructor, but it is not the name of anything because there is no destructor, hence "pseudo".

Answer (score 1):

**No compilation error**

 - The behavior is correct as **obj.~T();** means its a function call on the object. Calling a function is not a compilation error.

**Code runs fine**

- This behavior is undefined. Why you are not getting any error on running is because its a very simple class with not even primitive type data members let alone complex type members.

What is happening here is that in Main the destructor is called twice for object d. Once with call to ptrDest, and second implicit destruction when exiting from main function.
The destructor being so simple compiler puts its code inline. which is just a harmless cout. If you do same with complex class with destructor doing something with data member, it would certainly cause problems.